# migrate svn to subdirectory of git

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I'd like to replace my svn repository with git. Unfortunately I can't do this in one shot and to cut a long story short, I need to move an svn repository, with history, into a subdirectory of a pre-existing git repository. So I currently have:

```
svn:
svn1/
svn2/

git:
git1/
  .git/
  gita/
```

And I want:

```
svn:
svn1/

git:
git1/
  .git/
  gita/
  svn2/
```

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clone the svn repo with git-svn to preserve history and then merge it with the git repo.

For example:

```
git svn clone path_to_svn_repo
```

This will create a new git clone of the svn repo.
Now go to the directory with your git repo and merge the just-cloned as a normal git repo:

```
cd git-repo
git pull path_to_converted_git_repo
```

Comment: This seemed to work. I did something along the lines of the following:
<pre>
git-svn clone svn2
git mv svn2dirs svn2/svn2dirs

in a separate area:
git clone git1
git branch svn
git checkout svn
git pull svn2
git checkout master
git merge svn
git push
</pre>

Answer (score 0):

Once you have two git repo, you can try [**link them together**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600498/git-and-multiple-repositories/2601082#2601082) through **grafts techniques**.