# How do I import one specific SVN branch to a git repository?

Tags: git, branch, git-svn

We recently moved from SVN to Git, but there's a single legacy branch that I need to bring in to the Git repository. The SVN and Git repositories are the same logical code (i.e. they're both called foo-lib), but the Git one has newer revisions from after we switched to Git.

Is there a way we can use git-svn to grab the history of a specific branch and graft it into the history of the git tree?

Comment: kind of related question, which may be of interest here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159282/migrate-svn-to-subdirectory-of-git

Comment: You should post that as an answer because it's pretty darn close to what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on VonC's comment, I took a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159282/migrate-svn-to-subdirectory-of-git) and did something like:

```
git svn clone -A ~/.git/svn.authors http://svn/branches/foo svn-foo
git clone git@git:blah/foo.git new-foo
cd new-foo
git pull ../svn-foo :old-foo
```