# How do I Re-root a git repo to a parent folder while preserving history?

Tags: git

I have a git repo in `/foo/bar/baz` with a large commit history and multiple branches.

I now want `/foo/qux` to be in the same repo as `/foo/bar/baz`, which means that I need them both to be in a repo rooted at `/foo`.  However, I want to preserve history of changes that I've made to `/foo/bar/baz`.

I first thought of git format-patch followed by apply, but commit messages aren't preserved.

So,

I need to reroot the repo

(1) to an arbitrarily higher ancestor directory
(2) while preserving my commit history by making it look like I've been comitting to `/foo/bar/baz` all along

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm working through your suggestions now.  I can't move /foo/baz, but the other two seem promising.

Comment: I do not believe this question is a duplicate, as there are actually 4 different questions and answers detailed by these two questions: 1a. How do I move my git repo *down* one directory? 1b. How do I move my git repo *down* one directory and make it look like it was always that way? 2a. How do I move my git repo *up* one directory? 2b. How do I move my git repo *up* one directory and make it look like it was always that way? The answer to 1a and 2a are basically the same, but 1b and 2b are entirely different, yielding 3 different valuable answers.

Comment: As pointed out by the OP and others, the labelling of this question having answers elsewhere is incorrect; the question linked-to, is in fact the reversal of this one. Moreover, the accepted answer given here is both unique and superior to any that can be found there or at other candidates.

Comment: I voted to reopen

Comment: And it appears to have worked out; the duplication labelling is gone and the answer section is open again. Tx. I'll move my answer here and tidy-up.

Comment: This is a duplicate of "how do I move a folder"...: `mv /foo/qux /foo/bar/baz/` `git add /foo/bar/baz` `mv /foo/bar /foo`

Comment: @DanielW. will, say, `git status bar/baz/<somefile>` output after you do this? (assuming `git status <somefile>` initially worked too).

Comment: Why do you want to change the current project? Just copy the folder in it like you would normally create a folder or file.

Comment: @DanielW: Your way would work, if I am at liberty to restructure the file layouts. In the OP that wasn't an option.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you want is `git filter-branch`, which can move a whole repository into a subtree, preserving history by making it look as if it's always been that way.  Back up your repository before using this!

Here's the magic.  In `/foo/bar`, run:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    TREE="$1";
    shift;
    SUBTREE=`echo -e 040000 tree $TREE"\tbar" | git mktree`
    git commit-tree $SUBTREE "$@"' -- --all
```

That will make the `/foo/bar` repository have another 'bar' subdirectory with all its contents throughout its whole history.  Then you can move the entire repo up to the `foo` level and add `baz` code to it.

*Update*:

Okay, here's what's going on.  A commit is a link to a "tree" (think of it as a SHA representing a whole filesystem subdirectory's contents) plus some "parent" SHA's and some metadata link author/message/etc.  The `git commit-tree` command is the low-level bit that wraps all this together.  The parameter to `--commit-filter` gets treated as a shell function and run in place of `git commit-tree` during the filter process, and has to act like it.

What I'm doing is taking the first parameter, the original tree to commit, and building a new "tree object" that says it's in a subfolder via `git mktree`, another low-level git command.  To do that, I have to pipe into it something that looks like a git tree i.e. a set of (mode SP type SP SHA TAB filename) lines; thus the echo command.  The output of `mktree` is then substituted for the first parameter when I chain to the real `commit-tree`; `"$@"` is a way to pass all the other parameters intact, having stripped the first off with `shift`.  See `git help mktree` and `git help commit-tree` for info.

So, if you need multiple levels, you have to nest a few extra levels of tree objects (this isn't tested but is the general idea):

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    TREE="$1"
    shift
    SUBTREE1=`echo -e 040000 tree $TREE"\tbar" | git mktree`
    SUBTREE2=`echo -e 040000 tree $SUBTREE1"\tb" | git mktree`
    SUBTREE3=`echo -e 040000 tree $SUBTREE2"\ta" | git mktree`
    git commit-tree $SUBTREE3 "$@"' -- --all
```

That should shift the real contents down into `a/b/bar` (note the reversed order).

**Update**: Integrated improvements From Matthew Alpert's answer below.  Without `-- --all` this only works on the currently-checked out branch, but since the question is asking about a whole repo, it makes more sense to do it this way than branch-by-branch.

Comment: Hi,  I ran into a snag by oversimplifying the situation.  The repo I want to move to /foo is not /foo/bar; it is actually /foo/a/b/bar.  I think the basic idea behind your approach still works, but I can't rewrite a nested path:

git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    TREE="$1";
    shift;
    SUBTREE=`echo -e 040000 tree $TREE"\ta/b/bar" | git mktree`
    git commit-tree $SUBTREE "$@"'

Rewrite 27814f8d447ca9a4b61ed17a33912bee41e2e00e (1/68)fatal: path a/b/bar contains slash

Also, I can't figure out what your script does...could you explain? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I figured it out.  Nope, nevermind, I didn't figure it out.

Comment: In particular, I don't understand this part:

tree $TREE"\tbar"

As I am interpreting the filter-branch manpage,
$TREE should hold a SHA1 commit (I'm assuming that's what TREE_ID is, though I've never seen "ID" anywhere else in git terminology).  The bash command tree "<SHA1>\tfoldername" does not yield a tree.  Thus we're not piping anything useful into git-mktree.

Comment: Okay, I've added a section explaining what's going on, and providing a way to do what you really want, more or less.

Comment: Had some trouble with this one. For some reason mktree keeps getting the -e parameter of echo along with the rest of the echo output?

Comment: weberwithoneb: What operating system are you running on?  GNU and bash echo both accept -e, but shells and /bin/echo binaries from older Unix systems (and maybe MacOSX?) might not, in which case you'll get the -e and literal backslash-T instead of tabs.  You can work around this by removing the -e and using control-V TAB to insert literal tab characters in the echo commands.  (Spaces won't work, mktree is picky about its whitespace.)

Comment: Should use `/bin/echo` else `echo -e` may not work. And maybe also `--tag-name-filter cat` to avoid "`WARNING: You said to rewrite tagged commits, but not the corresponding tag.`"?

Comment: Note it "preserves" the commits list but rewrites them changing their SHA1. This is not exactly what Git means about "preserving history": here history is changed.

Comment: On MacOSX, I firstly had to download the gnu coreutils (I used homebrew) and then I replaced `echo -e` with `/usr/local/bin/gecho -e` to remove the `input format error` message — and then this works great.

Comment: There is much simpler than that. See below answers

Comment: Now my history is duplicated. Maybe you should append a fix for this?
My current situation (git log) (you should paste this somewhere else because the formatting is messed up...):

    * merge remote and local after the filter-branch trick
    |\
    | * commit B
    | * commit A
    |/
    * saved work here before filter-branch trick
    * commit B
    * commit A

Comment: With the advent of `git >= 2.22.0` there is an easier alternative to this technique using [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), as follows: 

```git filter-repo --path-rename :bar/
```

Answer (score 16):

Rather than create a new repository, move what's in your current repository into the right place: create a new directory `bar` in your current directory and move the current content in (so your code is in `/foo/bar/bar`).  Then create a `baz` directory next to your new `bar` directory (`/foo/bar/baz`).  `mv /foo /foo2; mv /foo2/bar /foo; rmdir /foo2` and you're done :).

Git's rename tracking means that your history will still work and Git's hashing of content means that even though you've moved things around, you're still referencing the same objects in the repository.

Comment: I can't move things at will.  I initialized my repo in the wrong place, but the file hierarchy is correct as it is.  Thank you for suggest though.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that the end result look any different than you start with, just that moving things around as an intermediate step might help you get what you need.  Sorry if my answer wasn't very clear on that.  Note that the filter-branch answer also winds up with the repository that should be in `/foo` being in `/foo/bar` and needing to be moved.

Comment: I can’t easily follow your description, could you somehow reformat it? It’s rather dense and hard to see what you are doing exactly.

Comment: Where does `foo2` come from?

Comment: Oh, I got it. Maybe doing a graphic would simplify the process. I think it’s not half as hacky as the accepted answer, since it doesn’t involve the risk of screwing up the internals of your whole repository.

Answer (score 8):

This specifically answers "**how do I move my git repo up one or more directories and make it look like it was always that way?**"

With the advent of `git >= 2.22.0` [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) can be leveraged to rewrite history to appear as if that parent directory had always been part of it.

This is the same thing that [@Walter-Mundt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3212697/5110545) accomplishes using `git filter-branch`, but is simpler and not as fragile to execute.

Note that these days `git filter-repo` is [advertised by `git filter-branch` itself as the safer alternative](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_warning).

---

So, given that your repo lives in `/foo/bar/baz` and you want to move it up to `/foo`

First, to prevent any changes to the files in the workspace while history is being rewritten, temporarily turn the repository into a so-called ["bare"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5543277/5110545) one like this:

```sh
cd /foo/bar/baz
git config --local --bool core.bare true
```

The actual history rewriting can now be done directly in the `.git` directory itself:

```sh
cd ./.git
git filter-repo --path-rename :bar/baz/
```

This will rewrite the repo's complete history as if every path has always had `bar/baz/` prepended to it (which they would have had, had the repo's root been two levels up).  The actual files are untouched by this operation because this is a bare repository now.

To wrap up, turn it un-bare again, move the `.git` directory up to its designated position, and reset:

```sh
git config --local --bool core.bare false
cd ..
mv ./.git ../..
cd ../..
git reset
```

I think, the `git reset` cancels the after-effects of the repository having been  turned bare and back again. Try a `git status` before doing `git reset` to see what I mean.

A final `git status` should now prove that all is well, modulo some new untracked files in `/foo/qux` to deal with.

**CAVEAT** - if you try the above on an un-cloned repository, `git filter-repo` will refuse to do its magic *unless* you `--force` it to... Have a backup at the ready and consider yourself warned.

Answer (score 6):

I had a solution no one seems to have said yet:

What I specifically needed was to include files from the parent directory in my repository (effectively moving the repo up one directory).

I achieved this via:

- move all files (except for .git) into a new subdirectory with the same name. And **tell git about it** (with `git mv`)
- move all files from the parent directory into the now empty (except for .git/) current directory  **and tell git about it** (with `git add`)
- commit the whole thing into the repo, which **hasn't** moved (`git commit`).
- move the current directory up one level in the directory hierarchy. (with command line jiggery-pokery)

I hope this helps the next guy to come along -- I'm probably just having a brainless day, but I found the answers above over-elaborate and scary (for what **I** needed.)  I know this is similar to Andrew Aylett's answer above, but my situation seemed a little different and I wanted a more general view.

Comment: Sheesh.  It's a lot easier to just move the .git directory up one directory, and commit -a on that.   I have **got** to stop being afraid of git!

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple--thank you for this!  Also--be careful w/your .gitignore.  Folder paths in that are also relative & the first time I tried this I wound up missing a dir I wanted b/c it was listed in .gitignore.

Comment: I, too, followed the above answers, but they add unmerited complexity. My needs were a simple directory reordering, as originally mentioned. I created the desired 'new' org and then `git mv $i new/path/` using a simple shell loop. Afterwards, no complaining on git push, nor did I have to force my push, no lost history, so I suspect this may be the better answer.

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer. Should have more up votes for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please expand on the last step, to move the current directory up one level ? What was the command line jiggery-pokery ? Is it sufficient to just move everything ? In that case even in a desktop window this could be done, couldn't it ?

Comment: It's been a while since I did this, and my first comment came after I realized an easier way to do almost the same thing.  Try this:  Just move the .git folder up one directory, and then tell git about everything with `git add .` and `git commit`.  You could, indeed, move the directory using a gui window, and exactly how you do the git stuff depends on how you're using git.  The commands I give are how you'd do it from a terminal window (probably Git Bash, if you're using Windows.)

Comment: Oh, and @Vic, as Roy says, if you have ignored files or anything else in your .gitignore, you should keep an eye on what you're committing to make sure it's correct.  You'd probably need to change your .gitignore entries (just prefixing them with the new directory) in that case.

Comment: @JonCarter, thanks for the swift reply and the precisions. I think your first solution would work best for me, because the second solution would probably end up with git not considering that files have moved, but that all were deleted, and many files created. I always have to use git mv otherwise I get that. So I think I'll use your first solution. Thanks a lot !

Comment: The 'jiggery-pokery' I mentioned in the original answer was for moving the original directory up one level by copying everything in the directory to the upper one, then delete the now-empty subdir.  In other words, after you move everything from the upper directory *down* in order to include it in the git repository, you are left with a repo where the top-level directory has just one entry - the one with the repo in it.  So you then just move everything in it back *up* one level, and delete the subdir you just moved everything out of.  Sorry if that isn't clear.. it's simpler than it sounds.

Answer (score 6):

### Most common solution

In most normal situations, git looks at all files relatively to its location (meaning the .git directory), as opposed to using absolute file paths.

Thus, if you don't mind having a commit in your history which shows that you have moved everything up, there is a very simple solution, which consists in moving the git directory. The only slightly tricky thing is to make sure git understands that the files are the same and that they only moved relatively to him :

```
# Create sub-directory with the same name in /foo/bar
mkdir bar

# Move everything down, notifying git :
git mv file1 file2 file3 bar/

# Then move everything up one level :
mv .git ../.git
mv bar/* .
mv .gitignore ../

# Here, take care to move untracked files

# Then delete unused directory
rmdir bar

# and commit
cd ../
git commit
```

The only thing to be careful, is to correctly update .gitignore when moving to the new directory, to avoid staging unwanted files, or forgetting some.

### Bonus solution

In some settings, git manages to figure out by itself that files have been moved when it sees new files that are exactly the same as deleted files. In that case, the solution is even simpler :

```
mv .git ../.git
mv .gitignore ../.gitignore

cd ../
git commit
```

Again, be careful with your .gitignore

Comment: I did that with success to add a second part of an application, thanks

Answer (score 5):

This adds to Walter Mundt's accepted answer. I would have rather commented on his answer, but I don't have the reputation.

So Walter Mundt's method works great, but it works only for one branch at a time. And after the first branch, there may be warnings that require -f to force the action through. So to do this for all branches at once, simply add "-- --all" to the end:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    tree="$1";
    shift;
    subtree=`echo -e 040000 tree $tree"\tsrc" | git mktree`
    git commit-tree $subtree "$@"' -- --all
```

And to do this for specific branches, add their names to the end instead, although I can't imagine why you would change the directory structure of only some of the branches.

Read more about this in the man page for git filter-branch. However, please notice the warning about possible difficulties pushing after using such a command. Just make sure you know what you're doing.

I'd appreciate more input on any potential problems with this method.

Comment: This one best worked for me. However my bash (Ubuntu Server 12.04) wouldn't parse echo -e parameter properly (I got fatal: "... input format error: -e 040000 tree ..."), so I've created alias echo='echo -e' and removed parameter from the command to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

1 addition to the accepted answer, which helped me get it to work:
when I put the listed text in a shell script, for some reason the -e was kept.
(quite likely because I am too thick to work with shell scripts)

when I removed the -e , and moved the quotes to encompass everything, it worked.
SUBTREE2=`echo "040000 tree $SUBTREE1       modules" | git mktree`

note that there is a tab between $SUBTREE1 and modules , which is the same \t that -e should interpret.

Comment: You could use `/bin/echo` instead of `echo` and keep the `-e`

Comment: To elaborate on Julien's comment here, the `echo` command is often, in various shells, implemented as a builtin.  Depending on *how* it's implemented, the options may work differently.  

As Julien recommended, it's possible to skip the issue of which echo you're using by calling `/bin/echo`, which is a standalone executable with standard behavior that is *not* dependent on any particulars of whatever shell the user may be running.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a git repo in `foo` and reference both `baz` and `bar` through **[`git submodules`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194)**.

Then both `bar` and `baz` coexist with their full history preserved.

---

If you really want only one repo (foo), with both bar and baz history in it, then some [grafts technique or subtree merge strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600498/git-and-multiple-repositories/2601082#2601082) are in order.