# How to establish a common ancestry with a fork in Git?

Tags: git

I have a git repository containing a fork of project foo:

```
origin/master
+src/
|  +foo/
|     +A/
|     +B/
|     +C/
+stuff/
```

I also have a mirror of project foo:

```
upstream/master
+foo/
   +A/
   +B/
   +C/
```

I do not yet have in git a common ancestry. I would like to both establish a common ancestry to make future merges easier and merge in any changes from the upstream foo that have been made since I forked.

I attempted to rebase my changes to `foo` on top of the upstream:

```
C:\src>git rebase -s recursive -X subtree=foo/ --root upstream/master
```

But, that did not work the way I desired. I ended up with `origin/master` looking exactly like `upstream/master` with none of my changes included and completely missing `stuff`.

```
origin/master
+foo/
   +A/
   +B/
   +C/
```

What do I need to do to merge upstream `foo` with my `src/foo`?

Am I limited to doing something like this?

```
C:\src>git merge upstream/master -s recursive -X subtree=foo/
```

Comment: Just to be clear, it looks like your fork has added a layer of nesting to the directory structure. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. The `foo` sub directory in `origin/master` is based on the root of `upstream/master`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use a `git filter-branch` to rewrite `upstream` as if `foo/` had been `src/foo/` from the start. Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/3212697/54249:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    TREE="$1";
    shift;
    SUBTREE=`echo -e 040000 tree $TREE"\tsrc" | git mktree`
    git commit-tree $SUBTREE "$@"' -- --all
```

That should give us:

```
upstream/master
+src/
   +foo/
      +A/
      +B/
      +C/
```

At this point you should be able to simply merge `upstream/master` into `origin/master`, giving a `git log --oneline --graph --decorate` that looks something like this:

```
*    (HEAD, master) Merge branch 'master' of upstream
|\
| *  (upstream/master) fourth upstream commit
| *  third upstream commit
* |  (origin/master) fourth origin commit
| *  second upstream commit
* |  third origin commit
| *  first upstream commit
*    second origin commit
*    first origin commit
```

Here's a proof of concept for a pair of local repositories - note the `git pull` reports "warning: no common commits":
[image: Proof of Concept]

Comment: Thanks, Keith. I'll try this when I get back in the office on Monday.