# Move .git repo to parent directory

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a subdirectory named "www" that is a repo:

```
site
|-- www/
|    |-- .git/
|    |-- index.html
|-- design/
|    |-- images.jpg
```

I'd like to change the repo to the parent directory so that the repo structure mirrors the original file structure as follows:

```
site
|-- .git/
|-- www/
|    |-- index.html
|-- design/
|    |-- images.jpg
```

Can this be done? Are there implications with then pushing the changes up to Gitlab?

Comment: I think you can just move the .git/ directory up a directory (or two). It's going to be sort of expensive, and that first commit is going to be interesting, but it should work. (based on the second answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918111/my-git-repository-is-in-the-wrong-root-directory-can-i-move-it-instead-of )

Comment: @mrcheshire Using `git mv` gives me a fatal error that says the destination directory "is outside the repository".

Comment: Just use `mv`. Then `git add -A`, `git commit -a`

Comment: @maackle This loses all revision history and looks like the files were deleted

Comment: In the current state, is `design` under revision control (i.e., a peer of `.git`?

Comment: @rholmes no, it is not. `www` is the root of the repo currently.

Comment: Roland Smith's answer **should** work.  Not sure if user541051's will (I've never tried) bit it may - it appears based on the answer mrcheshire points to.  Just make a backup of your repo before doing anything drastic ;-)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

1. Create a `www` directory in your repo.
2. `git mv` the HTML files to that directory. Optionally commit this step.
3. `mv` the design directory into your repo, and `git add .`
4. Commit.
5. Rename/move your whole repo.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Such a simple solution too!

Comment: By the `git mv` in step 2. this will - temporarily / until step 5 completes - move your files to a different place in the filesystem which _may_ be undesirable when these files serve any kind of live purpose - like being a web server's content for example.

[The solution given by @user5241051](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32083479/5110545) does not have this flaw.

Comment: Repositories are for development. Almost by definition the content of the working tree will be in flux. Using that as live webserver content would be ill advised, to say the least.

Comment: While that is very true,  git _does_ get used for [other purposes](https://hackaday.com/2017/05/23/stupid-git-tricks/).

Comment: To those that carried out this Git repo move, I have a question.  What happens if I carry out these steps, then try to reset to (or checkout) a commit that occurred before this move?  Will there be any issues?  For example, will the Git repo somehow move *back* to its original directory?

Comment: Succinct and elegant... thank you!

Answer (score 21):

The following instructions will work.

```
cd www
mv .git ../
git add www
git commit -a -m "Change root directory of project"
git add design/*
git commit -m "Start tracking design folder"
```

This will preserve your history.

Comment: You lose all hisotry on your files when doing this.

Comment: @NAIT If I do `git log` the history is preserved but on GitHub the history is removed.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Having said that, another method that rewrites history as if the parent directory has always been part of the repo can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60394780/5110545). Pushing changes is likely to need `--force` though.

Comment: Can you please explain how this works? It seems counter intuitive. Doing this I realized that git does a rename, but what is happening behind the scenes?

Comment: Should there be an extra step after 2 `cd ..`, or was that implicitly expected, seeing not everyone is an idiot like me...