# Accidentally put git into directory outside of the main directory I wanted

Tags: git, unix, github, directory

So I put git into folder B, but it needs to be in folder C. Folders go A>B>C

I'm worried to just move folder C to folder A because some of the files are already using their current path available to them.

Is there a clean way to just move the repo from B to C?

(Using Mac/Unix)

Answer (score 1):

you can use git mv to move files to the new location.

```
git mv <old path> <new path>
```

Read this to learn more about it:

https://githowto.com/moving_files

Also take a look on this question if you need something more complex:

[How do I Re-root a git repo to a parent folder while preserving history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212485/how-do-i-re-root-a-git-repo-to-a-parent-folder-while-preserving-history)

Answer (score 1):

As far as Git is concerned, you can just move the directory to a new location. Git stores all of its internal metadata in the hidden `.git` directory contained within the root directory so if you move the root, that will move with it.

Comment: Doing so will result in the files to be tracked as new files since the paths has been modified.

Comment: No it won't. I just set up a test repository, added a commit and then moved the directory to a brand new location on my drive. `git status` shows "nothing to commit, working directory clean" and `git log` shows my test commit.